# How to copy file names matching a pattern in powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I am new to powershell. I need to copy the whole folder structure from source to destination with filenames matching a pattern. I am doing the following. But it just copies the content in the root directory. For example

> "E:\Workflow\mydirectory\file_3.30.xml"

does not get copied.

Here is my sequence of commands.

```
PS F:\Tools> $source="E:\Workflow"
PS F:\Tools> $destination="E:\3.30"
PS F:\Tools> $filter = [regex] "3.30.xml"
PS F:\Tools> $bin = Get-ChildItem -Path $source | Where-Object {$_.Name -match $filter}
PS F:\Tools> foreach ($item in $bin) {Copy-Item -Path $item.FullName -Destination $destination}
PS F:\Tools> foreach ($item in $bin) {Copy-Item -Path $item.FullName -Destination $destination -recurse}
```

Comment: Similar question [powershell-match-file-name-and-copy][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6580725/powershell-match-file-name-and-copy